# Reload listview when receive data from web

Tags: android, timer, timertask

I receive every 30 seconds data from web. The problem is that data from listview is not refreshing. I user this code :

```
t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doReload1();

            }
        }, 300, 30000 );

public void doReload1() {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                            public void run() {
                                System.out.println("Every 30 sec getPlaylist");

                                try {
                                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                    String link = "http://test.res-novae.fr/sfr/imalive.php?device_key="
                                            + deviceId + "&device_type=9";
                                    System.out.println("trimit " + link);
                                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(link);
                                    try {
                                        httpclient.execute(httppost);
                                        GetPlaylists();

                                        System.out.println("getplaylist");

                                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                   });
```

and for populate the listview :

```
if (playlists.length != 0) {
            MyListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MyListView);
            adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, playlists);

            MyListView.setAdapter(adapter1);
}
```

I get from the web data for listview but it is not displayed on screen. Plase help..I spent a lot of time with this:(

Here is my playlists array :

```
try {

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                /* Checking response */
                if (response != null) {
                    String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response
                            .getEntity());
                    System.out
                            .println("Rezultat de la server :" + responseBody);

                    String jsonString = responseBody.toString();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

                    jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("_playLists");

                    playlists = new String[jArray.length()];
                    idPlaylist = new String[jArray.length()];
                    timerPlaylist = new String[jArray.length()];

                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jsdata = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = jsdata.getString("id_playlist");
                        String namePlaylist = jsdata.getString("name");
                        String timer = jsdata.getString("timer");
                        System.out.println("Name playlist" + namePlaylist);
                        playlists[i] = namePlaylist;
                        idPlaylist[i] = id;
                        timerPlaylist[i] = timer;
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        System.out.println("playlists : " + playlists[i] +"\n");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like a refresh problem. Have you logged on the console the content of the array playLists when you set the adapter?

Comment: yes, it has the corect data.the result from web looks like this : {"_playLists":[{"id_playlist":"33","name":"SFR Demo","timer":"2"},{"id_playlist":"49","name":"Second`playlist","timer":"1"},{"id_playlist":"50","name":"trei","timer":"1"}]} and playLists contains "SFR Demo","Second`playlist","trei"

Comment: Could you try to overwrite playLists before you create the adapter. For example add this line before creating the adapter. String[] playlists = new String[] { "Item0", "Item1", "Item3" };

Comment: now i get "Item0", "Item1", "Item3" on screen. So on playlists is not put the data from web :| Do you see where could be the problem?

Comment: It seems the data in playLists is not exactly what the adapter is waiting for. Make sure playLists is an array of Strings String[]. Try to trace the content of playlists like this before creating the adapter to see what's in : for (String item:playlists) { Log.d("DEBUG","item="+item); }

Comment: i edited my question how i put items to playlists array.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4779/discussion-between-jptsetung-and-gabrielle)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a network request on the UI thread - which will cause ANRs if the request takes too long. Do the Http stuff in the thread you make, and then update the list view inside the runOnUIThread call.. or alternatively use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (playlists.length != 0) {
            MyListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MyListView);
            adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, playlists);

            MyListView.setAdapter(adapter1);
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: nothing change...the listview is not update. I tried calling adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged(); on to many places but nothing is changing

Comment: you are downloading songs every 30 sec.until then,listview might not get completely updated causing UI to stick.so you are not able to see the update. for now,make it every 2 min. so that,listview can get time to be updated and you can see the changes.

Comment: there are not songs...are just names of some playlist and the interval time must be 30 sec

Comment: @Gabrielle: but if you continue using 30 sec interval,you might never see updated listview because it get more time than this one to get refreshed and let you see the updated one.